# Synchronize Azure AD user profiles with SharePoint Online Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile, profile-sync, azure-ad

How can I Synchronize Azure AD user profiles with SharePoint Online Users, to get the employeeId property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a custom property that you want to sync you need to look at the PnP guidance for how to sync these properties. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP